# How to make text selectable in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

I want to make some texts selectable by user so that she can copy and paste it. How can I make a text in a Label element selectable in Nativescript on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TextView

If you can change it to a `TextView` ***iOS*** will default to this behaviour.

- Set `editable="false" so the user can't edit your text. And to prevent the keyboard from appearing.
- `iOS` will apply a white background. Set `backgroundColor="transparent" to stop this.
- On `Android` you will need to set `args.object.nativeView.setTextIsSelectable(true)` *(i.e. from the views `loaded` event)*. You would need to do this even if you stick to using a `Label`.

```xml
<TextView 
  editable="false"
  text="Your text goes here"
  backgroundColor="transparent"
  android:loaded="makeSelectable" />
```

```js
exports.makeSelectable = args => args.object.nativeView.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

---

#### Label

If you want *(or need)* to stick to using a `Label` I'd say you have two options;

1. If you want the user to be able to select just part of your text with the native text selection UI

   - For `iOS` look into `UIMenuController`.
   - For `Android` just `setTextIsSelectable` again.
2. If you just want the user to be able to copy the whole text to clipboard, attach a `longPress` event to your `Label`. Then grab the `object.text` and add it to the clipboard, either by working with the native APIs or the [Clipboard](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-clipboard) plugin. I recommend the plugin.

   - On `iOS` the `longPress` event will fire twice. So to make sure you don't copy the text twice you can check `args.ios.state`. This will return the constant **1** when the press begins, and **3** when it ends.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do same thing in the past and i came up with [HTMLView](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ns-ui-widgets/html-view). The only thing i had to do was to use inline styling for fonts and other stuffs:

```
<HtmlView html="<span style='font-size:16px;color:#8f8f8f;margin:3px 0;font-family: Open Sans;'>{{oVPC.data}}</span>" textWrap="true" class="data" (tap)="onOpenLinkInWebBrowser(oVPC.data)"></HtmlView>
```